# What is the most concise way to get an injected bean for a springboot managed class?

Tags: groovy, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I have a simple application that injects another component

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
class Application {

  static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application, args)
  }

  @Bean
  AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
    return MY THING HERE
  }

}
```

I'd like a quick/minimal way to new this up and grab the item springboot wires up (for tokenServices in this example). I'm trying to get at this to verify some configuration/settings/etc using TestNG

I should also say that I"m not using any xml to configure this (using gradle/groovy/springboot)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write an integration test where the specific bean is injected into the test?

Comment: correct- I'd like to manually wire up an object (that springboot would normally do for you) so I can test configuration for a specific bean / etc (not using the xml based writing).

Comment: So you want to start the spring context, but you want to be able to provide a certain implementation of the specific bean - that will be injected into the test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily introduce conditional bean with the help of Spring profiles.

In your case the code would look like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("tokenService")
public TestTokenServiceConfig {

   @Primary
   @Bean
   AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
     //implementation
   }   
}
```

The custom implementation you supply in this class will only be used by Spring in case the profile `tokenService` is active. The use of `@Primary` is needed in order to make Spring use the specified bean instead of any others present in the application context.

Also note that since you are going to be using the custom service in a test environment, you could easily mock the implementation using Mockito (or whatever other mocking framework you prefer)

And the actual integration test would be something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("tokenService")
class YourIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    //test
}
```

Comment: excellent! and just to clarify - the "profile" here would pull in what properties file (and from what location -the test directory?)

Comment: Spring Boot will automatically load `application.properties` (from the classpath - which in the test case would from the test directory) and from `application-tokenService.properties`